# SharePoint 2013 app icon for library template

Tags: sharepoint

I created a feature (solution) which deploys a library template for SharePoint 2013. If I use this template to create a new library I go "Settings -> Add an app". There each app has a tile with an icon. Now my question is if I can change this Icon in my List Definition or anywhere else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the Image attribute of the ListTemplate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ListTemplate
        Name="MyList"
        Type="10012"
        BaseType="1"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="110"
        DisplayName="My List"
        Description=""
        Hidden="false"
        Image="/_layouts/images/itdl.png"
        DocumentTemplate="121"/>
</Elements>
```